# How to save Color Profile after calibrating using ColorMunki?

Tags: windows-10, color-profiles

I purchased ColorMunki Display to calibrate my Windows 10 display. After running their software to calibrate, it shows me a before/after color profile and it looks like it did a good job calibrating my monitor.

But it seems the color profile is set only while the ColorMunki software is running. I like to keep my PC clean with minimal software running. Is there a way to keep the calibrated color profile after colormunki is uninstalled?

I have checked the Windows 10 Color Management application. I see a .icm profile added by ColorMunki Display but it is not what I thought it is. If I set it as default profile, my display will be reset to uncalibrated profile.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did not see a solution for this. A display is just a display. What is wrong with Windows 10 Color calibration?  Settings, Calibrate Display Color (enter this in the Settings Search box)

Comment: @John - what's the point of spending all that money on a colorimeter if you're then going to use Windows own hokey calibration? Less than useless advice. some user - see https://www.xrite.com/service-support/monitorprofileunloadingonwindows7windows8windows10 I've never done this on Windows, only on Mac, so can't help much further. Windows ought to be able to load your icc by default once the XRite app is finished. I know Win has issues with more than one display, but the primary ought to be fairly easy.

Comment: Windows Calibrate Color works fine on all my machines. It is not a hotkey. I may check it once a year or so. It does not "load" anything that I know of; it sets colors and leaves it. I was surprised by any need to spend money on the same thing - just my own view, please undestand.

Comment: @John - I didn't say it was "a hotkey" I said it was **hokey**. Manual calibration is in no way a substitute for correct calibration using a colorimeter. Without one, you have no idea if your screen is correct or not. All you have is a guess, what 'looks nice to you'. If you need a calibrated workflow, you need better than a guess.